# After use 'index_file' => FALSE in bootstrap.php, i recive error "Object not found!" from my browser

Tags: php, kohana

I use kohana 3.3 and I have a problem!
Before use `'index file' => FALSE` all functions worked well. In url address I had `/localhost/angel/index.php/au/login`. After using `'index file' => FALSE` in the url address `/localhost/angel/au/login` and I get an error `Object not found!`.

How do I make the function `login` from the class `au` is called without `index.php` and everything works again? I can't understand why not working?!

Comment: "Object not found" is not a system error. Can you show trace log?

Comment: Sry but I do not know how to do trace log. 
I see tutorial in youtube where after use 'index file' => FALSE all works fine.

Comment: Screenshot with that error?

Comment: with 'index file' => FALSE [link](https://googledrive.com/host/0B9tr9fXb0r7LNko1SGxOeUJLOWc/Screenshot%20from%202013-05-07%2014:43:59.png)

without [link](https://googledrive.com/host/0B9tr9fXb0r7LNko1SGxOeUJLOWc/Screenshot%20from%202013-05-07%2014:44:35.png)

Comment: Its an Apache error page. Read http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/tutorials/clean-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like .htaccess problem. Check if Apache ModRewrite is enabled.

Comment: And i thing the same. But where is this .htaccess file in XAMPP on ubuntu? I cant find.

Comment: It should be in your root application directory.